# Why is this component rendering twice upon state change?

Tags: reactjs

I am coding a `React` Header component that will slide out on scroll. (code is at the bottom)

- I assign an event handler in the `useEffect` hook, and it will call the `handleChange` function when a scroll event occurs. I have wrapped this `handleChange` function in a `useCallback` hook for performance ( no need to reinstantiate on every render ).
- I am also wrapping the entire function with `React.memo`.
- I store the scroll position in a `useRef`, because a change doesn't need to trigger a rerender, the rerender will be caused by the `setVisibility` inside `handleChange`.

Now, this component is rendering more times than I would expect. I have added a console.log to every 'action' in my component to track what is happening. I have copied the Chrome DevTools console output.
Upon mounting, the console shows:

```
Render 0
Render 0
Added event listener
```

Why does it render twice before even running useEffect?

When I scroll on the page, the console shows:

```
Handling scroll
Previous scroll: 249.5625
Scroll: 251.5625
Render 249.5625
Render 249.5625
Handling scroll
Previous scroll: 251.5625
Scroll: 252.5625
Render 251.5625
Render 251.5625
Handling scroll
Previous scroll: 252.5625
Scroll: 254.5625
```

So my `handleChange` function is called, but it rerenders the component twice every time the scroll position is changed?

**Please help me figure out why this component is rendering twice when the state changes.**
EDIT: I've found that it can even render 4 times when it slides out or back in.

```
//I'm using styled-components and the prop simply tranforms the header up when the visible prop is true
function Header(): JSX.Element {
  const [visible, setVisibility] = useState(true);
  const scrollPosition = useRef(0);

  const handleScroll = useCallback(() => {
    //Non-absolute values will result in comparison errors
    const currentScrollPosition = Math.abs(
      document.body.getBoundingClientRect().top
    );

    //Testing
    console.log("Handling scroll");
    console.log("Previous scroll:", scrollPosition.current);

    console.log("Scroll:", currentScrollPosition);

    //Do not hide when scrolling down for the first time until user scroll down a little
    if (currentScrollPosition <= 150) {
      setVisibility(true);
    } else setVisibility(scrollPosition.current > currentScrollPosition);

    //Update ref value to new scrolling position
    scrollPosition.current = currentScrollPosition;
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);

    //Testing
    console.log("Added event listener");

    return (): void => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);

      //Testing
      console.log("Removed event listener");
    };
  }, []);

  //Testing
  console.log("Render", scrollPosition.current);

  return (
    <>
      <S_header visible={!visible}>
        <h3>Work on preventing excessive rendering </h3>
      </S_header>
    </>
  );
}

export default memo(Header);
```

Comment: why can't I replicate your issue while pasting your code to codesandbox ? https://codesandbox.io/s/misty-brook-k1m16?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark , it just renders once

Comment: I am using Next.js but that shouldn't have any impact whatsoever because the component doesn't have any props

Answer (score 0):

I think because onScroll fires multiple times so naturally you will get multiple trigger. Best practice is to use debounce or throttle, depends on your need. I show here my version with debounce

```
import { debounce } from 'lodash/fp';
import React, { useEffect, useCallback, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const propTypes = {};
const defaultProps = {};
const Component = ({}) => {
  const [visible, setVisibility] = useState(true);
  const scrollPosition = useRef(0);

  const handleScroll = useCallback(debounce(200, () => {
    // Non-absolute values will result in comparison errors
    const currentScrollPosition =     Math.abs(document.body.getBoundingClientRect().top);

    // Testing
    console.log('Handling scroll');
    console.log('Previous scroll:', scrollPosition.current);

    console.log('Scroll:', currentScrollPosition);

    // Do not hide when scrolling down for the first time until user scroll down a little
    if (currentScrollPosition <= 150) {
      setVisibility(true);
    } else setVisibility(scrollPosition.current > currentScrollPosition);

    // Update ref value to new scrolling position
    scrollPosition.current = currentScrollPosition;
  }), []);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);

    // Testing
    console.log('Added event listener');

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);

      // Testing
      console.log('Removed event listener');
    };
  }, []);

  // Testing
  console.log('Render', scrollPosition.current);
  return (
    <div visible={!visible}>
      <h3>Work on preventing excessive rendering </h3>
    </div>
  );
};
Component.propTypes = propTypes;
Component.defaultProps = defaultProps;
export default Component;
```

throttle usage, https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#throttle